# How to mock up an "NHoldSubset" property

Tags: function-construction, attributes

I have a numeric function `f` for which I would like the action of `N` to act only on the last two arguments (and more generally, on any chosen subset of a function's set of arguments).

More concretely, I'd like the following behavior

```
f[1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/6] // N
(* f[2, 3, 4, 1/3, 0.25`, 0.1667`] *)
```

Neither `SetAttributes[f, NHoldAll]`, `SetAttributes[f, NHoldFirst]`, nor `SetAttributes[f, NHoldRest]` will do the job.

---

I've tried making the definitions the following definitions, the result of calling `N[f[1, 1/2, 1/3, 1/4, 1/6]]` is summarized after each definition.

```
(*1*) N[f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_]] := f[a, b, c, N[d], N[e]];
      (* Leads to an infinite recursion, but output is correct *)
```

and

```
(*2*) SetAttributes[f,NHoldAll];
      N[f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_]] := f[a, b, c, N[d], N[e]];
      (*Same behavior as 1*)
```

and

```
(*3*) HoldPattern[N[f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_]]] := f[a, b, c, N[d], N[e]];
      (*N incorrectly applies to all arguments*)
```

and

```
(*4*) SetAttributes[f,NHoldAll];
      HoldPattern[N[f[a_, b_, c_, d_, e_]]] := f[a, b, c, N[d], N[e]];
      (*N fails to apply to any argument*)
```

---

**Question** How do I mock up a behavior of `N` such that it only applies only to a subset of its arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea is to use `f[{a, b, c}, d, e]` with [`NHoldFirst`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NHoldFirst). Or, you can try:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, NHoldAll];

f/:N[f[a_,b_,c_,d_,e_], def_.] := Module[{new=N[{d,e}, def]},
    Replace[new, {x__} :> f[a,b,c,x]] /; new=!={d,e}
]
```

The condition prevents the infinite recursion.

Comment: This is excellent!  I'm improving upon this by using the following:  (1) No `TagSetDelayed` since assignments to `N` are anyway tagged to the inside symbol.  (2) `With` instead of `Module` and (3) Apply anonymous Function `f[a, b, c, #1, #2] & @@ new` instead of replacement `Replace[new, {x__} :> f[a,b,c,x]`.  (not sure about performance improvement on point 3 though).